# Default value for Lombok @Value without @Builder

Tags: java, jackson, lombok

Is there a way to provide default value for fields under model annotated with `@Value`.
For example:

```
@Value
class Book {
  String title;
  List<String> authors;
}
```

In above model, Jackson deserializes authors to `null` from json payload that has authors as `null`, but I want author to have a `[]` as default value as opposed to `null`.
I know below won't work because field becomes `private final` due to `@Value`

```
  List<String> authors = Collections.emptyList();
```

I could override the all args constructor but the model itself is quite large so I am looking for something similar to `Builder.Default` but for `@Value`.

Comment: What's the reason you do not want `@Builder`?

Comment: `@Builder` with `@Singular` is fine. I was looking for a liner solution since there is only one such field that is list. The model I have to work with is quite large with many levels of nested classes, since a lot of tests are written using model's and their children's allargsconstructor, it's quite a pain to modify to builder

Answer (score 1):

You can add your own constructor which initializes your `authors` field.

```
@Value
@AllArgsConstructor
static class Book {
    String title;
    List<String> authors;

    public Book(String title) {
        this(title, Collections.emptyList());
    }
}
```

`@AllArgsConstructor` was required as, when a custom constructor was added, `@Value` skipped all field constructor generation.